# Rake task to copy database.example.yml to database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

Getting error while copying database.example.yml to database.yml through rake task

**copy_files.rake**

```
namespace :copy do
  desc "copy database.yml & application.yml"
  task :config_files => :environment do
    source = File.join(Rails.root, "config", "database.example.yml")
    target = File.join(Rails.root, "config", "database.yml")
    FileUtils.cp_r source, target
  end
end
```

**Error**

```
$ rake copy:config_files
rake aborted!
Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:105:in `database_configuration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:128:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => copy:config_files => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I see that the error is because there is no database.yml file. Is there any possible way for copying database.yml file through a rake task?

Comment: I think the answer is  - NO. Because for running rake tasks you need valid environment and it is impossible without `database.yml`. Maybe you can say reason why you would like to copy database through rake task, maybe it is better to do through ruby script.

Comment: There is an example given here, http://blog.envylabs.com/post/68063567445/rake-file-tasks, But not sure where to the write the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised!!! But @SrikanthJeeva is right :)

I managed to run rake task without `database.yml`. You should remove `:environment` and you can't use `Rails.root` (because you can't load Rails without database.yml). This works for me

```
  desc "copy database.yml & application.yml"
  task :config_files do
    source = File.join(Dir.pwd, "config", "database.example.yml")
    target = File.join(Dir.pwd, "config", "database.yml")
    FileUtils.cp_r source, target
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

As @gotva mentioned in above comment, you need a "valid" environment to run rake tasks with `=> :environment`. This way, rake task loads the Rails environment and it needs a `database.yaml` file.

You can achieve that with a script or, for example, using Ruby into a IRB session:

```
$ cd /app_rails_root_path
$ irb
> Dir.glob("config/*.yml.example").each { |f| FileUtils.cp(f, f.gsub(/\.example/,'')) }
```